# How do I create a random number based on a seed without using random.seed()?

Tags: python, random

I know that you can do this:

```
random.seed(100)
r = random.randint(1, 3)
```

But is it possible to do something more similar to this?

```
r = random.randint(1, 3, seed=100)
```

Also I am aware that the code above would give the same output every time, that is the behavior I want.

Comment: If you want it to give the same output every time, just write `r = 4`.

Comment: @jasonharper Except it would be `r = 1` since the range is `randint(1, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Create your own RNG](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.Random) with the seed you want, and call its `randint` method:

```
r = random.Random(100).randint(1, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Put `random()` inside a wrapper.  I can't write Python, so this is pseudocode:

```
myRandom(lo, hi, mySeed)
  random.seed(mySeed)
  return random.randint(lo, hi)
```

I will leave converting that to correct Python as an exercise.